# A solution for unready drives in vb6

Tags: vb6, error-handling, drive

I need a better solution for handling unready drives and want to be able to see and change files in my rw-drive. Unfortunately it always gives drive unready error and the only thing that I can do is handle the error.

So far I've done this:

My Drive:

```
Private Sub imperialdrive_Change()
    On Error GoTo I_have_a_baad_feeling_about_this
    imperialdir.Path = RootPathOnDrive(imperialdrive.Drive)
    Exit Sub

I_have_a_baad_feeling_about_this:
    If Err.Number = 68 Then
        MsgBox "The selected drive is not available at the moment.", vbOKOnly, "I feel a disturbance in the force."
    Else
        MsgBox Err.Number & " " & Err.Description, vbCritical, "There is a Bounty Hunter here."
    End If
End Sub
```

My Function:

```
'Such a bad choise for a function name
'It sounds like doing smt more than changing the name of drive lol
Public Function RootPathOnDrive(ByVal Drive)
    'So how it comes as "k:" instead of "k:\" Is it really cause its not ready? Both ways i should try reaching "k:\"
     RootPathOnDrive = Left(Drive, 1) & ":\"
End Function
```

Comment: @Deanna ty for "Rewritten in English and formatted code slightly better." lol 
actually ur better than me in vb6 i hope u can find an answer about this. I'm still searching the web for it but no proper answer found.

Comment: Sorry, I could have sworn I toned down my change message :p Error handling may be your ownly option if the system reports the drive is unavailable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked into using the FileSystemObject that is part of the Microsoft Scripting Runtime (scrrun.dll)?

```
Public Function CheckDrivePathReady(IN_sPath as String) As Boolean
    Dim myFSO As Scripting.FileSystemObject
    Dim myDrive As Scripting.Drive
    Dim myDriveName As String

    'Create a new FileSystemObject
    Set myFSO = New Scripting.FileSystemObject

    'Get drive name from path.
    myDriveName = gFSO.GetDriveName(IN_sPath)
    'Create a "Drive" object to test the properties of.
    Set myDrive = gFSO.GetDrive(myDriveName)

    'Test if the drive is usable.
    '(there are more properties than just "ready" that can be tested)
    If myDrive.IsReady Then
        'Work with ready drive here....

    End If

    'Make sure to clean up when done.
    set myDrive = Nothing
    Set myFSO = Nothing
End Function
```

You will need to include the Microsoft Scripting Runtime in your project references, but I have found the FileSystemObject to be invaluable when working with drives and paths.

Comment: Yea this have done a better job than on err.. I can define lots of drive situations with this. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

What is imperialdir?  E.g., is it a filelistbox?
Is the problem that the Path property always throws an error when you try to set it, even with a path you know exists, like "k:\" ?  Some objects have a Path property that is read-only.
Better name for function CheckDrive would be RootPathOnDrive.

Comment: its a vb6 component called DirListBox and im using it with DriveListBox as every other people does usually when having some folder works in their projects with vb6..